# Camel ActiveMQ rollback not rolling back

Tags: transactions, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to put together a trivial example of a Camel ActiveMQ route that will rollback transactions.

This should;

- create a timer to create a message every second
- send the timer's message to ActiveMQ
- rollback the transaction

In the logs, I see it trying to rollback the transaction, but I see the messages in the queue.  My expectation would be that the message wouldn't make it to the queue.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```java
import org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultRegistry;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

public class PushToQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory= new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        JmsTransactionManager transactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        DefaultRegistry registry = (DefaultRegistry) context.getRegistry();
        registry.bind("txmanager",  transactionManager);
        ((org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext) context).setRegistry(registry);

        context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory,transactionManager));

        context.setMessageHistory(true);

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer:activemq-timer")
                        .transacted()
                        .log("created message  ${id} with body ${body}")
                        .to("activemq:MY_QUEUE_1")
                        .log("finished send to queue  ${id} with body ${body}")
                        .rollback();
            }
        });

        while (true)
            context.start();
    }

}
```

Here is the output;

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Routes startup summary (total:1 started:1)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Started route1 (timer://activemq-timer)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.9.0 (camel-1) started in 116ms (build:40ms init:62ms start:14ms)
[ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://activemq-timer] INFO route1 - created message  3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000 with body 
[ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://activemq-timer] INFO route1 - finished send to queue  3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000 with body 
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://activemq-timer] WARN org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.DefaultErrorHandler - Rollback (MessageId: 3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000) due: Intended rollback. Exchange[3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [from[timer://activemq-timer]                                                  ] [       188]
[route1            ] [transacted1       ] [transacted                                                                    ] [         0]
[route1            ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [activemq:MY_QUEUE_1                                                           ] [        26]
[route1            ] [log2              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route1            ] [rollback1         ] [rollback                                                                      ] [         0]

[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://activemq-timer] WARN org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler - Transaction rollback (0x6af93788) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: 3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000) caught: org.apache.camel.RollbackExchangeException: Intended rollback. Exchange[3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://activemq-timer] WARN org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer - Error processing exchange. Exchange[3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.RollbackExchangeException: Intended rollback. Exchange[3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000000]]
[ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://activemq-timer] INFO route1 - created message  3AC2457AAE3A8FA-0000000000000001 with body 
...
```

Comment: Looking at the code, there appears to be two connection factories being used.  The one I create (and is used in the BEGIN/ROLLBACK transaction), and another one that is being used by camel to do the actual message sending.  This 2nd one is created in ActiveMQConfiguration#createConnectionFactory.

Comment: I think I figured it out;  

 ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent();

        activeMQComponent.setTransacted(true);

        activeMQComponent.setTransactedInOut(true);

        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        activeMQComponent.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);

        context.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent);